# Creating a single dataframe by merging multiple CSVs from the same folder

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]

listdf = []

for f in files:

    filename, ext = os.path.splitext(f)

    if ext == '.csv':

        listdf.append(filename)

        filename = pd.read_csv(filename + '.csv', index_col='responseid')

listdf

interim_df = reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, on='responseid'), listdf)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\rpy2-2.9.4-py3.6-win-amd64.egg\rpy2\robjects\pandas2ri.py:191: FutureWarning: from_items is deprecated. Please use DataFrame.from_dict(dict(items), ...) instead. DataFrame.from_dict(OrderedDict(items)) may be used to preserve the key order.

  res = PandasDataFrame.from_items(items)
       ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-71b6f0ea0884> in <module>
 55 listdf
 56 
--->     57 interim_df = reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, on='responseid'), listdf)
```

```
   in <lambda>(x, y)
 55 listdf
 56 
---> 57 interim_df = reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, on='responseid'), listdf)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
 59                          right_index=right_index, sort=sort, suffixes=suffixes,
 60                          copy=copy, indicator=indicator,
---> 61                          validate=validate)
 62     return op.get_result()
 63 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in __init__(self, left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, axis, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
522         if not isinstance(left, DataFrame):
523             raise ValueError('can not merge DataFrame with instance of '
--> 524                              'type {left}'.format(left=type(left)))
525         if not isinstance(right, DataFrame):
526             raise ValueError('can not merge DataFrame with instance of '
```

**ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type**

Comment: ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'str'>

Comment: all your csv;s have same columns?

Comment: No, they have different col names except for the index which is 'responseid'

Comment: df=pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in os.listdir('.') if file.endswith('.csv')])
df.set_index('responseid',inplace=True)

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in os.listdir('.') if file.endswith('.csv')]) 
df.set_index('responseid',inplace=True)
```

Comment: I apologize for not being clear earlier. Each data frame here has different number of rows so I am wondering if concat will help.

Comment: post two sample df's with different shape and its expected output